# Serializing a field as json

Tags: java, json, jackson, resttemplate, jackson-databind

I need to send a JSON body to REST service. Unfortunately, service is quite old and I need to send a POJO, containing JSON string field. So it looks like this:

```
class SomeData {
    int id;
    SomePojo jsonField;

    ...
}
```

So SomeData should be sent like this:

```
{'id': 1, 'jsonField': some_json_string}
```

I haven't found any Jackson magic annotation to make it works and I've got a doubt it can be made somehow because of type erasure in Java and it may not be possible to write custom serializer for this purpose but I'm not sure.

Could you please suggest any idea of how I can make it work or workaround the issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Lino Hi Lino, thanks for the answer! Sure. but it implies I should implement my own custom serializer, shoudn't I?

Comment: Look up for `org.simple.json` you can easily create a `json` out of a class instance, using the class getter.

Comment: I think google gson might be what you are looking for. It can very easily convert a POJO to JSON and vice versa. It also is very good in processing nested POJOs.

Comment: @Asew Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but how can O serialize the field in this way?

Comment: @Mitch Hello Mitch, ok, thank you, I'm sure I'll try it but at first I would like to stay as simple as I can

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich Add a getter for id, and a getter for jsonField (which could return a string representation of it to make thing easier). Then you should just add a method `toJson()` in your class that do something like `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(this)`

Comment: @Asew Lino helped me a lot and I managed to have it working. However, your solutions seems interesting to me, I didn't know about it. I'll be trying it out, could you post the answer if you have time too? I think there might be less code

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich I've posted an answer, if you would like to see a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using Jackson in a Spring context, you can make use of the [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html)-Annotation

Assuming you have the Classes from your question, then you can put the above mentioned annotation on your getter:

```
public class SomeData {
    int id;
    SomePojo jsonField;

    @JsonSerialize(using = PojoSerializer.class)
    public SomePojo getJsonField(){
         return jsonField;
    }
}
```

Then creating the `PojoSerializer`:

```
public class PojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SomePojo>{
    @Override
    public void serialize( SomePojo pojo, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider ) throws IOException{
        jsonGenerator.writeString(pojo.getSomeString());
    }
}
```

The rest does spring for you

Comment: Seems like a solution! Just a minute and I'll try it!

Comment: Wait, but why `@JsonDeserialize`?o_0 I need to serialize it as json:) But I got the idea

Comment: oh then I understood you wrong, so you want to serialize the field as a string then? If so, its just the other way round, the @JsonSerialize on your getter with the according serializer class

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: happy to hear that

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your own serialiser, you can then configure it at `ObjectMapper` level, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(SomeData.class, new SomeDataSerialiser());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

You can find the complete example [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

Comment: Works, great, thank you! but Lino was the first to start the discussion, all I can do is to up you answer:C

Answer (score 1):

As asked, I'll post a simple example of `org.json`.

Class sample :

```
import org.json.*;
public class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private String randomString;

    public MyClass(int id_, String randomString_){
        this.id = id_;
        this.randomString = randomString_;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getRandomString() {
        return randomString;
    }

    //Uses the getter to generate a JSon representation of the class
    public JSONObject toJson(){
        return new JSONObject(this);
    }
}
```

Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass test = new MyClass(1, "Test");
    System.out.println(test.toJson().toString());
}
```

Output : `{"id":1,"randomString":"Test"}`

You can download the Jar [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810).

You can find the full documentation [here](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/package-index.html).

Also this [link](https://www.codevoila.com/post/65/java-json-tutorial-and-example-json-java-orgjson) for more usage examples.

Comment: No problem, also, if your class as an attribute that is a class of your, lets say `AlsoMyClass`, as long as this class also as getters, it will also get properly formated into `json`.

Comment: the problem is here, however, that I can't change the class, representing the field:c and I have to send it with `RestTemplate`. so it was not an option for me to convert to json strong manually

Comment: Well then, you just have to code the 'getPojo()' to return a string representation of your attribute. It will also work.