# How to deserialize nested JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gson, json-deserialization

JSON

```
    "entities": {
        "nca_location": [
            {
                "confidence": 0.85126983589896,
                "value": "struga",
                "type": "value"
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0.9188255680843,
                "value": "Skopje",
                "type": "value"
            }
        ],
        "intent": [
            {
                "confidence": 0.99990092463824,
                "value": "nca_get_position_availability"
            }
        ]
    }
```

EntityDto

```
public class EntityDto {
    private String name;
    private List<EntityValueDto> values;

    public EntityDto(String name, List<EntityValueDto> values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public List<EntityValueDto> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<EntityValueDto> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

EntityValueDto

```
public class EntityValueDto {
    private Float confidence;
    private String value;

    public EntityValueDto(Float confidence, String value) {
        this.confidence = confidence;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    public void setConfidence(Float confidence) {
        this.confidence = confidence;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

How can I use GSON/Jackson to make this sort of mapping automatic? I would like to only extract the entities values and make a list out of them.

EntityDto example: nca_location would be the name, and the list would be the parsed objects.

```
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);
```

This is how I get the response object from the API and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know how to use `gson` and `jackson`, but if you're willing to use org.json I could help you. Here's a simple example of how it works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826568/6370796. Mind that you can also create an object with a `json`

Comment: Use [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for json/pojo converting. And change ...Object.class with newly generated class.