# Deserialize some fields in a json to a different class

Tags: java, json, class, jackson, deserialization

I have a json of below format:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "alternateId": 0,
    "familyName": "",
    "givenName": "",
    "firstName":"",
    "lastName": "",
    "middleName": "",
    "suffix": "",    
    "motherName": "",
    "datOfBirth": "",
    "sex": "",
    "alias": [
        {
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "middleName": "",
        "suffix": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can observe, four fields `firstName`, `lastName`, `middleName`, and `suffix` which are present in the `alias` field are also present above it as fields of parent class.

Currently I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    private int     id;
    private int     alternateId;
    private String  familyName;
    private String  givenName;
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastName;
    private String  middleName;
    private String  suffix;
    private String  motherName;
    private Date    datOfBirth;
    private String  sex;
    private Set<Alias>  alias;
}

public class Alias
{
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastName;
    private String  middleName;
    private String  suffix;
}
```

And its working good with the jackson mapper. But my question is can the fields which are in Person class be combined to a new field primaryAlias and class be reduced to :

```
public class Person
{
    private int     id;
    private int     alternateId;
    private String  familyName;
    private String  givenName;
    private Alias   primaryAlias;
    private String  motherName;
    private Date    datOfBirth;
    private String  sex;
    private Set<Alias>  alias;
}
```

without changing the current json. Can something be done to write a deserialiser in jackson which will map the fields `firstName`, `lastName`, `middleName`, and `suffix` of the json to be loaded into the new variable `primaryAlias`?

No need for complete code to do so, but a hint of what to do will be enough. I tried searching but maybe I am missing the perfect terminology to describe this problem.

Maybe I can explain better with images. This is whats currently happening:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Comment: I have deleted the response. But in your JSON, `alias` is a list, so you cant do it automatically... Maybe you can itereta ove the JSOn and create the object manually.

Comment: @canillas Yes. That I know. I was thinking of maybe an automatic jackson solution by annotations and custom deserializer.

Comment: If you use org.json instead, you could do it. With this library, a JSON representation is made out of the `getter` of the class. Hence, if you create a method `getPrimaryAlias()` that return whatever string you want, it will work. Here's an example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826568/6370796

Comment: I'm testing with your JSOn and maybe you can use `@JSONProperty`in a setter, not in a property directly. If you use @JsonProperty("id") in i.e. `public vod doSomething(int id)` mean that when Jackson is going to map your property called id, the method will be executed. maybe you can use this.

Comment: How can anyone down-vote this possible perfect question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your rescue, comes [`@JsonCreator`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) which gives control to you before creation of class, so that you can populate the properties yourself :)

Here is my quick work (I have just used limited properties of your big json). Similarly my toString method is just to reflect that properties are loaded. You can have a meaningful toString if you want.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class JacksonTest {

    final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String jsonInString = "{\n"
                + "    \"id\": 0,\n"
                + "    \"familyName\": \"someFN\",\n"
                + "    \"givenName\": \"someGivenName\",\n"
                + "    \"firstName\":\"firstNameInperson\",\n"
                + "    \"lastName\": \"\",\n"
                + "    \"middleName\": \"\",\n"
                + "    \"suffix\": \"\",    \n"
                + "    \"motherName\": \"\",\n"
                + "    \"alias\": [\n"
                + "        {\n"
                + "        \"firstName\": \"firstNameInAlias\",\n"
                + "        \"lastName\": \"\",\n"
                + "        \"middleName\": \"\",\n"
                + "        \"suffix\": \"\"\n"
                + "        }\n"
                + "    ]\n"
                + "}";
        //System.out.println(jsonInString);

        Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
        // System.out.println(newFoo.getSomething());
    }
}

class Person {

    @JsonProperty
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String familyName;

    Alias alias;

    @JsonProperty
    private String motherName;
    @JsonProperty
    private Set<Alias> aliases;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        System.out.println("printing in constructor.." + properties);
        id = (Integer) properties.get("id");
        familyName = (String) properties.get("familyName");
        Alias al = new Alias();
        al.firstName = (String) properties.get("firstName");
        al.lastName = (String) properties.get("lastName");
        al.middleName = (String) properties.get("middleName");
        al.suffix = (String) properties.get("suffix");
        this.alias = al;
        TypeReference aliasesType = new TypeReference<Set<Alias>>() {
        };
        try {
            aliases = JacksonTest.mapper.readValue(JacksonTest.mapper.writeValueAsString(properties.get("alias")), aliasesType);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person: familyName:" + familyName + ", Alias: " + alias + " Aliases:" + aliases;
    }

}

class Alias {

    @JsonProperty
    String firstName;

    @JsonProperty
    String lastName;

    @JsonProperty
    String middleName;

    @JsonProperty
    String suffix;

    public String toString() {
        return "Alias : firstName::" + firstName;
    }
}
```